# Obtain a different line chart type when creating an excel chart within Python

Tags: python, excel, charts, openpyxl

I want to create a line chart within Python of a specific type. I am using the library openpyxl. The piece of code used gives a different chart type to the one I am looking for and do not know how to change it to get the desired plot.

I have gone through the line chart documentation here:https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/line.html
But they do not seem to address this.

```
from openpyxl.chart import (
    LineChart,
    Reference,
)

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook( r"file.xlsx")
ws=wb.active
c1 = LineChart()
c1.title = "Line Chart"
c1.style = 13
c1.y_axis.title = 'value'
c1.x_axis.title = 'Time'

data = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=2, max_row=5)
c1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
ws.add_chart(c1, "A10")
wb.save("Result.xlsx")
```

If the next table is used, the type of graph retrieved has the shape of left side chart. I want to get a graph along the lines of the right hand chart instead.[image: Type obtained vs Type desired]

Comment: You need to use a ScatterChart instead https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/scatter.html

Comment: @CharlieClark Thanks but I do not see how would that solve the issue. Could you elaborate it more?